# Login values from react not passing to springboot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

So I'm developing a project with spring boot and spring security for the backend and React v6
for the frontend. I was getting a 403 forbidden error when I tried to post my login page with axios and fixed it with [this post][1] but now when I post my values I get an error like this:

```
ERROR 16160 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception 
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148) ~[na:na]
    at gr.hua.dit.referenceLetterApp.model.UserDetailsImpl.getPassword(UserDetailsImpl.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
```

My UserDetailsImpl is this:

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Optional<User> user;

public UserDetailsImpl(Optional<User> user) {
    super();
    System.out.println(user);
    this.user=user;


}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {


    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities=new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+this.user.get().getRole().toUpperCase()));

    return grantedAuthorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return this.user.get().getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return this.user.get().getIt();
}


@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {

    return true;
}

public Optional<User> getUserDetails() {
    return user;
}

public String hasRole(){
    return this.user.get().getRole();
}}
```

My userDetailsServiceImpl:

```
 @Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    Optional<User> user=userRepo.findByIt(username);

    System.out.println("inside impl "+user);

    if(user==null) {
        System.out.println("exception thrown");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + "not found");
    }
    return new UserDetailsImpl(user);
}}
```

My securityweb config:

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000/login")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;

@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {

    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    String[] staticResources  =  {
            "/static/**",
            "/resources/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/vendor.jquery/**"
    };

    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/request/form").hasRole("STUDENT")
            .antMatchers("/request/owned").hasRole("STUDENT")
            .antMatchers("/requests/sendTo").hasRole("TEACHER")
            .antMatchers("/requests/approved").hasRole("TEACHER")
            .antMatchers("/requests").denyAll()
            .antMatchers(staticResources).permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login").successHandler(loginSuccessHandler).permitAll()
            .and().logout().permitAll();



    http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();


}
```

And lastly this is my login page in react:

```
class Login extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        errors: { username: '', password: '' }
    };
}

returnUser=()=>{
    return {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
    };
}
handleChange = (e) => {

    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
};

login = () => {
    let user = this.returnUser();
    let errors = { username: '', password: ''};

    if (!user.username) {
        errors.username = 'Username is required';
    }

    if (!user.password) {
        errors.password = 'Password is required';
    }

    // Rest of validation conditions go here...

    this.setState({ errors });
    if(user.username&&user.password){

        axios.post("/login",user)
            .then(response =>{
                console.log(response.data);

            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error)
            });
    }


};
render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (

        <div className="outer login">

            <div className="inner">
                <form>
            <span className="login100-form-title p-b-49">
                    REFEЯRAL
                </span>

                    <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate="Username is required">
                        <span className="label-input100">Username</span>

                        <input value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} className="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Type your username"/>
                        <span className="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf2c0;"/>
                        {errors.username !== '' && <span className="error-nav" data-symbol="&#xf05a;" style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors.username}</span>}
                    </div>

                    <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                        <span className="label-input100">Password</span>
                        <input value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} className="input100" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Type your password"/>
                        {errors.password !== '' && <span className="error-nav" data-symbol="&#xf05a;" style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors.password}</span>}
                        <span className="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf084;"/>
                    </div>


                    <div className="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <div className="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                            <div className="login100-form-bgbtn"/>
                            <button type="button" className="login100-form-btn" onClick={this.login}>
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>


        </div>



    );
}

}
export default withRouter(Login);
```

I'm confused on what is going wrong but it might be something with the csrf headers. Anyone can help?
[1]: https://techinplanet.com/getting-a-post-403-forbidden-with-spring-boot-vuejs-and-axios-frontend/

Comment: Look at either [reactive-form-jwt-security-demo](https://github.com/karlnicholas/reactive-form-jwt-security-demo) or [webflux-jwt-security-demo](https://github.com/karlnicholas/webflux-jwt-security-demo). Also, don't use `Optional` as a class variable. Just `User` and return `Optional.ofNullable` for `getUser`.

Comment: @K.Nicholas, it's worth noting that with `spring-boot-starter-oauth-resource-server` dependency, you can support JWT authentication without a custom filter. See [OAuth 2.0 Resource Server JWT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html).

Comment: @Chris_Gr, I agree with @K.Nicholas, it appears you are using `Optional` incorrectly. You are likely dealing with a "User not found" situation, but surfacing that error at the wrong time. Instead of `if (user == null) ...`, try `return user.map(u -> new UserDetailsImpl(u)).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " not found"));`

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg - I agree and have seen that. The examples I worked out were meant both as a DIY approach and a JWT/Resource without external dependencies. I had some trouble understanding what the `spring-boot-starter-oauth-resource-server` was doing for me without experience beforehand about what OAuth was doing.

Comment: Cool. Just wanted to make sure you/others see that as lots of folks are rolling their own like your examples. For anyone interested, check out this [Tanzu Tuesday talk](https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/tv/tanzu-tuesdays/0061/) that gives details outside the context of oauth.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Thank you and K.Nickolas, i fixed the issues with Optional but that wasn't the main problem. I followed some instructions and implemented jwt on my blackened and some authentication on the react frontend and everything works fine now!